# reflect.Value.MapIndex() returns a Value different from reflect.ValueOf()

Tags: reflection, go

According to the reflect documentation `reflect.Value.MapIndex()` should return a `reflect.Value` which represents the Value of the data stored at a specific key of a map. So my understanding would be that the following two expressions should be identical. In the first case we are getting the result from `MapIndex()`. In the second we are getting the result from `MapIndex()` getting it's underlying data and then doing a `reflect.ValueOf()` on that.

```
reflect.ValueOf(map).MapIndex("Key")
reflect.ValueOf(reflect.ValueOf(map).MapIndex("Key").Interface())
```

**Why is the additional `reflect.ValueOf()` required?**

Example Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    test := map[string]interface{}{"First": "firstValue"}
    Pass(test)
}

func Pass(d interface{}) {
    mydata := reflect.ValueOf(d).MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("First"))
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v \n", mydata.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("Kind: %+v \n", mydata.Kind())
    fmt.Printf("Kind2: %+v \n", reflect.ValueOf(mydata.Interface()).Kind())
}
```

Go Play: http://play.golang.org/p/TG4SzrtTf0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this for a while this falls under the *duh* category. It has to do with the nature of `interfaces` in Go, which are reference objects which point to other things. I have explicitly declared my map to be `map[string]interface{}` meaning that the value at the location of each key is an `interface{}`, not a string, so I really shouldn't be surprised to receive a `reflect.Value` which holds an `interface{}`.

The additional `reflect.ValueOf()` dives one layer deeper to gain the underlying Value of the `interface{}`. I created two examples, both of which I believe confirm this behavior.

Example using a `map[string]Stringer` custom interface: http://play.golang.org/p/zXCn9Fce3Q

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Test struct {
    Data string
}

func (t Test) GetData() string {
    return t.Data
}

type Stringer interface {
    GetData() string
}

func main() {
    test := map[string]Stringer{"First": Test{Data: "testing"}}
    Pass(test)
}

func Pass(d interface{}) {
    mydata := reflect.ValueOf(d).MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("First"))
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v \n", mydata.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("Kind: %+v \n", mydata.Kind())
    fmt.Printf("Kind2: %+v \n", reflect.ValueOf(mydata.Interface()).Kind())
}
```

returns

```
Value: {Data:testing} 
Kind: interface 
Kind2: struct
```

Example using a `map[string]string`: http://play.golang.org/p/vXuPzmObgN

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    test := map[string]string{"First": "firstValue"}
    Pass(test)
}

func Pass(d interface{}) {
    mydata := reflect.ValueOf(d).MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("First"))
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v \n", mydata.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("Kind: %+v \n", mydata.Kind())
    fmt.Printf("Kind2: %+v \n", reflect.ValueOf(mydata.Interface()).Kind())
}
```

returns

```
Value: firstValue 
Kind: string 
Kind2: string
```

Comment: Whups and you answered while I was typing! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
func Pass(d interface{}) {
    mydata := reflect.ValueOf(d).MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("First"))
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v \n", mydata.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("Kind: %+v \n", mydata.Kind())
```

At this point in your program, mydata is an interface, so no surprises that Go reports it as such when Kind() is called.

```
    fmt.Printf("Kind2: %+v \n", reflect.ValueOf(mydata.Interface()).Kind())
```

Break this down:

```
s := mydata.Interface()  // s is a string
v := reflect.ValueOf(s)  // v is a reflect.Value
k := v.Kind()            // k is a reflect.Kind "string"
```

I think you may be being tripped up by the fact that your map contains interfaces, not strings.